# Oppenheim Signals, Systems & Inference

Tags: books

I intend to buy the book by Oppenheim et al, "Signals & Systems" 2nd edition.
Now I also find (also by Oppenheim et al) "Signals, Systems & Inference".

**Does anyone know, is this book the same but with slight changes, or is it completely different?**

Answer (score 6):

It's quite different from the older Signals and Systems book, and it builds on the knowledge acquired through that or a similar basic signals and systems text. Some of the topics covered are state-space models, pulse-amplitude modulation, probabilistic models, random processes, estimation and detection.

So if your goal is to get a good basic knowledge of signals and systems, then I'd recommend either the older Signals and Systems text, or one of the many other similar books. Also take a look at the book recommendations on this site.

—-

Added a screenshot from [this Amazon review:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133943283)

[image: review saying it needs better signals and system background]

Comment: Is there a specific place on this site that has book recommendations?

Comment: @Gillespie: Just look at questions with the [books](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag.